# System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol default value

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, ssl

On my first PC i have to use this line

`[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'ssl3,tls,tls11,tls12'`

before using network methonds/commands. But on my another PC network methods wroks without requiring this line.

How to set this values `'ssl3,tls,tls11,tls12'` as default for `SecurityProtocol`, to not using above line in every my code, like it is on my second PC?

Comment: I'm personally not aware of a way to persistently change the default, but given that you only need to run this command _once per session_, you could it put it in your  [profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles). However, given that it's possible to bypass profile loading, for robustness it should be part of any scripts that rely on it.